# Include a php file that is above WP installation hierarchically?

Tags: php, themes, include

I've come across a number of ways to call the WP "root" folder

But what if I want to include a php file that is in a parent folder of WP?

Example http://www.site.com/, where the WP blog is in http://www.site.com/blog/

So far I can't find anything on this topic, and including the absolute URL to the file isn't working

Comment: This is php question rather than a WordPress one, but you include a file not by its url but by its location on the server, probably something like /home/youraccountname/public_html/yourfile.php

Answer (score 0):

OK. I'm assuming you have Wordpress setup as a sub-directory of your root URL. If so, this should work:

```
<?php include 'http://www.site.com/file.php'; ?>
```

Sometimes people write the include special form with parentheses. In most cases it won't break anything, but if your code looks like this, try removing them:

```
<?php include('http://www.site.com/file.php'); ?>
```

Also, make sure that the "Wordpress Address" and "Site Address" are both set to the proper URL in the admin settings. This might throw off your absolute URL.

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem to be working, but it didn't break the page either. For now I have a separate include file in the WP root that is working